# Wordpress comments_template not working on AJAX call

Tags: wordpress

I've been having a problem getting comments_template to work when calling it in a function in theme functions using AJAX.  It works fine when it is called for the first page load, but not when called during AJAX.  I'm thinking that there's some include that's missing, but I don't know enough here to understand what.

Here's the essence of the function code that's in my functions.php file for my Theme. (the entire thing much longer)

```
function displayLargePost ($postid) {

// get the submitted postid parameter if set.
if (!$postid) {
    $postid = $_REQUEST['postID'];
}

$myposts = new WP_Query();
$myposts->query( 'p='.$postid );
while( $myposts->have_posts() ) : $myposts->the_post();

// some formatting stuff is done then output post content

the_content();

// some more formatting then output the comments template (doesn't work with AJAX)

comments_template();

}
```

`

Again, the function executes when the AJAX call is run, everything works except for the comments_template outputs '0'.

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE - Entire function after figuring out a workaround using include(comments.php)

```
function displayLargePost ($postid) {

if ($_REQUEST['action'] == "displayLargePost") {
    require_once("../wp-load.php");
    global $wpdb; 
    $postid = $_REQUEST['postID'];
    $ajax = 1;
}

$myposts = new WP_Query();
$myposts->query( 'p='.$postid );
while( $myposts->have_posts() ) : $myposts->the_post();
```

?>

```
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> data-postid="<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <div class="post-meta-mix clearfix">

            <h3 class="post-title post-title-mix"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                <p class="post-info ">
                    <span>By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
                    <?php the_time( 'l F j, Y' ) ?>
                </p>

        </div><!-- End div class="post-meta clearfix" -->

        <div class="socialdiv socialdiv-mix">

            <?php if (function_exists('tweetmeme')) echo tweetmeme(); ?>

                <div class="sharebutton">
                <fb:share-button href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" type="button"></fb:share-button>
            </div>
                <div class="likebutton">
                <fb:like href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="auto"></fb:like>
                </div>

            <?php if( get_post_meta( $myposts->post->ID, "itunes_link", true ) ) : ?>
                        <div class="ituneslink">
                                <?php echo get_post_meta( $myposts->post->ID, "itunes_link", true ) ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (get_post_meta( $myposts->post->ID, "track_number", true ) != '-1') : // Don't put the link to add to playlists on the mix intro post
                if (function_exists('wpfp_link')) { ?>
                    <div class="favplaylistlink">
                        <?php wpfp_link(); ?>
                    </div> 
            <?php } endif; ?>

        </div><!-- socialdiv -->

        <div class="post-box"><!--Single ID post box-->

            <div class="page-content clearfix"><!--Single ID post box-->

                <div class="clearfix monthlymix-box"><!--Single ID post box-->

                    <?php if( get_post_meta( $myposts->post->ID, "image_value", true ) ) : ?> 

                        <div class="post-image-inner post-image-mix left">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo get_post_meta( $myposts->post->ID, "image_value", true ); ?>&amp;w=300&amp;h=300&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                        </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>


                    <?php if( get_post_meta( $myposts->post->ID, "download_url", true ) ) : ?>

                                                                    <p>
                                                                   <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $myposts->post->ID, "download_url", true ) ?>" target="blank" type="image/png" >Download this Track</a>
                                                                    </p>

                    <?php endif; ?>


                    <?php 
                    // OUTPUT POST CONTENT
                    // Remove the YouTube embedded within post, add p tags to keep form
                    $text = preg_replace('/<center>httpv.*/','',get_the_content());
                    $text = str_replace("\n", "</p><p>", $text);
                    echo '<p>'.$text.'</p>';
                    ?>

                    <br />

                </div><!-- End div class="clearfix" --><!--Single ID post box-->

            </div><!-- End post-content clearfix --><!--Single ID post box-->

        </div><!-- End post-box --><!-- Single ID post box-->                   

        <div class="monthlymix-bottom">
            <div class="video-mix">
                <div class="post-meta clearfix">
                    <h3 class="post-title-small left">Video</h3>
                    <p class="post-info right">
                    </p>
                </div><!-- End post-meta -->
                <div class="youtube-mix">
                    <?php
                    if (get_post_meta( $myposts->post->ID, "youtube_url", true )) :
                        $video = get_post_meta( $myposts->post->ID, "youtube_url", true );
                        $video = preg_replace('/watch\?v=/', 'v/', $video);
                    ?>
<span class="youtube"> 
<object width="400" height="325"> 
<param name="movie" value="<?php echo $video; ?>" /> 
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /> 
<embed wmode="transparent" src="<?php echo $video; ?   >&amp;color2=febd01&amp;fs=1&amp;showinfo=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"     allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="325"></embed> 
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

```
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="commentbox-mix">
                <?php
                //comments_template(); 
                include('comments.php');
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- End post ID-->   

<?php 
endwhile; // end of while have posts from new WP Query
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().

if ($ajax) {
    die;
}

}

add_action('wp_ajax_displayLargePost', 'displayLargePost', 10, 1);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_displayLargePost', 'displayLargePost', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Why do you use comments_template(); in this function? Did you tried to call it after the displayLargePost() function? Give us the entire function.

Comment: Thanks for the response Vlad!  I use comments_tempate just because the theme uses it to call the comments.php code.  The entire function is below.  Quick update, the 0 came from die(0) which was in the admin-ajax.php file.  I got a workaround going by using include(comments.php) and declaring global $post $user_ID and $user_identity inside of the comments.php file.

Comment: Vlad, I validated that admin-ajax.php is loading wp-load.php, and that in turn should load the entire Wordpress structure, including comment-template.php which has a bunch of comment related functions in it.  For some reason though, it is not working.  There is no error when php hits 'comments_template()' though.  So maybe it sees it as a function but can't execute it?  The strange thing is that all the other stuff in The Loop works.

Answer (score 7):

comments_template only works for posts and single pages.
To make it work you need to use $withcomments = true like this:

```
global $withcomments;

$withcomments = true; 
comments_template();
```

I had a similar issue and solved it in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338672/wordpress-showing-comments-from-a-post-retrieved-with-ajax)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.