# wordpress showing comments from a post retrieved with ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

i'm loading a post with ajax.
The code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    loadPostsFun = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://lab1.koalamedia.es/ajax/",
            //url: "/random/",
            success: function(response){
                $("#randomPost").html( response );
            }
        });
    };
    $("#another").click(function(){
        loadPostsFun();
        return false;
    });
});
```

The response is generated by a custom template with this code:

```
<?php
    query_posts('showposts=1&orderby=rand');
    the_post();
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'date' );
    $rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
?>
<?php
    foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
      <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
        <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php } else { ?>
          <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php } ?>

         <div class="entry-content">
          <?php the_content(); ?>
          <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        <?php comments_popup_link(__('Comments (0)'), __('Comments (1)'), __('Comments (%)')); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
      </div><!-- #post-## -->

      <?php 

        //comments_template( '', true ); //this doesn't work
        comment_form(); 
        //wp_list_comments(''); //this doesn't work

      ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The ajax request works but the comments doesn't show.All the post data is there.
How can i show the comments?

neither comments_template or wp_list_comments work.

You can view a demo or download the template sample i've done [here](http://lab1.koalamedia.es/)

Comment: `comment_form()` will only show the input fields to submit a new comment, not any previous comments, so that's working as it should.
Do you get any output from `print_r( get_comments( array('post_id' => $post->ID) ) );`?

Comment: thv20, the problem wasn't in comment_form.The problem was the comments not showing.get_comments returns the correct data.I used it in my first approach but i had some problems getting all the info(reply link, classes...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've found the problem, i forgot to set the global variable:

```
global $withcomments;
```

i was using

```
$withcomments = true; 
comments_template();
```

but without the global it didn't work.

Now works like normal comments  do.

Comment: i mean , you set it in that ajax function ?

Answer (score 2):

Without much tweaking `wp_list_comments()` works in a comments template (usually `comments.php`) only.

Use [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments), pass the post ID as parameter:

```
$comments = get_comments(array ( 'post_id' =>  $post->ID );
if ( $comments )
{
    foreach ( $comments as $comment )
    {
        print "<li>$comment->comment_author<br>$comment->comment_content</li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: toscho, i tried that before and it worked but i had some problems creating the reply links and doing some format, like classes for even, odd, etc.That was my first approach and works too.